# How to enable hidpi pixel scaling in mac Screen Sharing app?

Tags: display, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I'm using my mac's Screen Sharing app to connect to VNC (vino) on a linux mint box.

The linux mint box has HiDPI (sort of like retina) pixel doubling enabled.

The problem is the shared screen is showing as gigantic windows and fonts and not the correct scaled size.

Any way to correct this?

Comment: Have you tried to "Turn Scaling On/Off"?

Comment: @klanomath toggling the "scale to fit" option makes no difference.